# Getting color of pixel from xy coordinates on multiple monitors

Tags: delphi

I have a pretty simple routine that used to work great when I only had one monitor but now it's giving wrong results. Basically, I have screen coordinates for my "main" monitor that I want to grab a color from an exact pixel location. The problem is that now the color actually changes, but when I run the code, it still gives the color from the first time HDC was assigned. So if the color is 255 (Red) the first time the procedure is called, then I change the color to 65280 (Green) and run the code again, it still comes up as 255. Also, this only works at all if I assign the HDC as a window handle. If I use 0 instead, the screen xy positions are way off (height is 0, width is something 6 million). So that's not working that way either. Any ideas?

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y: integer;
  r: trect;
  dc: hdc;
begin
  stat('Scan start');

  dc := GetDC(whwnd);
  getWindowRect(dc, r);
  stat('Left:   ' + inttostr(r.Left));
  stat('Top:    ' + inttostr(r.Top));
  stat('Width:  ' + inttostr(r.Width));
  stat('Height: ' + inttostr(r.Height));

  for y := 800 to 1000 do begin
    for x := 1 to 300 do begin
      tt := getPixel(dc, x, y);
      if tt = 0 then stat3(inttostr(x) + ',' + inttostr(y) + ' Black');
      if tt = 255 then stat3(inttostr(x) + ',' + inttostr(y) + ' Red');
      if tt = 65280 then stat3(inttostr(x) + ',' + inttostr(y) + ' Green');
    end;
  end;

  stat('Scan end');
end;
```

Comment: The coordinates for `GetPixel()` are relative to whatever you get the `HDC` from.  If you use a screen `HDC`, the coordinates are relative to the screen. But if you use a window `HDC`, the coordinates are relative to the window, not to the screen.

Comment: The fact that you get width that exceeds 6 million it is quite possible that `getWindowRect` actually failed so the values of `r` are just some random values since the said rectangle has never been properly initialized. I recommend you read [GetWindowRect function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) on how to properly handle possible errors.

Comment: Also have you perhaps thought about taking a screenshot of specific area of your window by using something like [Take a screenshot of a particular area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46989414/3636228) and then checking color of the specific pixel in captured image.

Comment: I thought about a screenshot but thought the timing wouldn't work out too well because this has to react to those color changes immediately. I'm not terribly concerned about knowing the width and height, as long as I can find out where to reference my changing pixel colors. I just changed it to GetDC(0) and added the check to make sure it's not null after assigning. But I still can't find my locations. I have almost 200 specific cursor positions (relative to the window) that I know are one of three color values and can't seem to find them when I use 0 instead of the actual window handle.

Comment: The main issue is that there seems to be a reference image created when first calling GetDC, and then is not updated during subsequent calls so the color values do not change at those points, even though they definitely have.

Comment: Based on the fact that you have so many possible locations the approach with screenshot might be better since you can then possibly split the load for checking each of these location into multiple threads. You won't be able to do this with `GetPixel`. Also when reading value for specific pixel in captured image don't use Pixel property but instead make use of [How to implement the scanline access of TBitmap correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400819/how-to-implement-the-scanline-access-of-tbitmap-correctly)

Comment: And if you are interested in tracking changes when they happen using of ScreenShot approach might offer another advantage since you can compare current ScreenShot aginst previous by using some Image comparison algorithm.

Comment: I'll look into the scanline method after I get home today. I don't have any use for history though. I feel like if I could just figure out why the color at the specific locations are never changing after the first GetDC with the window handle, then everything would be perfect. Or, if GetDC(0) does update automatically and I could find where my cursor positions are relative to the full screen, that too would work out well. The actual window that I'm checking for changes never changes position so I can hardcode the points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256107/discussion-between-user2021539-and-silverwarior).